# C++ function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

Is there a way in C++ to make an "untyed" function pointer ?
For example:

```
// pointer to global function
void foo( void (*fptr)() );

// pointer to member
void foo( void (Bar::*fptr)() );
```

Is there a way I can remove the class on which the member is ? So that I could do something like this:

```
void foo( void ("any type"::*fptr)(), "same type as for the pointer" &instance );
```

And then, in foo, I would like to store that pointer in a list, so that I can iterator over the list and call the function/member pointed to, regardless of what class it belongs to. Of course I'd need a list of instances on which to call the function.

Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a template.

```
template<typename T> void foo( void(T::*)(), T&) { ... }
```

However, people prefer to go for the function object approach. You can do this dynamically or statically.

```
void foo(std::function<void()> func) {
    // std::bind is used to make this out of a member function
}
template<typename T> void foo(T t = T()) {
    t(); // This is the best approach.
}
```

Edit: Some examples.

```
void foo(std::function<void()> func) {
    std::cout << "In example one ";
    func();
}
template<typename T> void foo(T t = T()) {
    std::cout << "In example two ";
    t();
}
class some_class {
public:
    void func() { std::cout << "in ur function!\n"; }
};
int main(void)
{
    some_class* ptr = NULL;
    struct tempfunctor {
        tempfunctor(some_class* newptr)
            : ptr(newptr) {}
        some_class* ptr;
        void operator()() { return ptr->func(); }
    };
    foo(tempfunctor(ptr)); // Calls example two
    foo(std::function<void()>(tempfunctor(ptr))); // Calls example one
    foo(std::function<void()>(std::bind(&some_class::func, ptr)); // I'm not that familiar with bind, it looks something similar to this.
    std::cin.get();
}
```

This is the idiom called the function object idiom, used heavily in STL and other high-quality libraries. The compile-time template is cleaner but the std::function can be bound at runtime.

Edit @ OP: I didn't quite see your list requirement in there. A `std::function<void()>` is your best choice here.

Comment: I've not used function objects that much, I'll give this a try, it looks pretty much like what I need.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if you don't need the generality offered by `std::function`, you may be better off using function pointers directly.  The polymorphic function wrappers do have overhead (typically around the same cost of calling a virtual function).  It's not a lot of overhead, and it won't matter in many applications, but it's worth remembering.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how do I use those examples ? I can't seem to get the first example to compile if I pass a member function to foo, and I have no idea what how to use the second example.

Comment: @__dominic: You use std::bind for the first one, it allows you to convert. For the second one, you write a function object.

Comment: @DeadMG  for function objects, which I call functors, I'm only used to use them as objects defining their operator(). You seem however to expose a cleaner way to construct them with template at compile time. However, the more I read your answer, the less I grasp it... could you point me to a simple example of the Function Object impletemented as a template ? Here the functor is defined in tempFunctor, which is not templated.

Comment: @Stephane: The template goes on the receiving function, not on the function object itself. This way, it can accept any function object. tempfunctor does not define the functor, tempfunctor *is* the functor.

Comment: Cool, I got this to work with member functions and global functions. Is there any reading you could recommend ? I don't fully understand how the examples work, I've not really ever used functors before. Thanks.

Comment: @DeadMG, Mmh, still pondering about it, much much clearer now, but I still don't grasp how it could perform when given a pointer to member function ? Could you enrich your answer with also an example of it ?

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: You don't give it a pointer to member function. You make a functor that does the same job. However, you certainly CAN use std::function and std::bind to make that work. I'm just not sure how since there's no benefit over writing a custom functor or using a C++0x lambda function (since I have a supporting compiler).

Comment: @DeadMG so are the std::function and std::bind C++0x only ?

Comment: @DeadMG, well I will have to play with VC2010 this week end to try master this a little. I am not used with std::bind neither.

Comment: @__dominic, @Stephane: They're part of Boost, and (I think) TR1, and C++0x. Stephane, if you have VC2010, just use lambda objects, much easier than any other solution,.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work fine with g++ and MSVC:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo( boost::function<int()> f )
{
    cout << "f() = " << f() << endl;
}

template< class Type >
void foo( int (Type::*f)() const, Type const& o )
{
    foo( boost::bind( f, boost::ref( o ) ) );
}

int func1() { return 1; }
struct S { int func2() const { return 2; } };

int main()
{
    foo( func1 );
    foo( &S::func2, S() );
}
```

Disclaimer: I seldom use the Boost stuff and I just typed the above without bothering to check the docs, so possibly it could be expressed more cleanly.

Also note that C++0x standard library offers the same functionality.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1, clean. You might want another overload `void foo( int (Type::*f)(), Type& o )` to support non-const members. The question had `void (Bar::*fptr)()` after all.

Answer (score 1):

No. The bound class is an intrinsic part of the member function pointer type.

You can, however, use a member function pointer to a common baseclass, or a template.

Comment: Yeah, for the moment I'm using a base class, but I was hoping there was a way I could do without it, ans I can't use a template since I want to keep them in a list, I'd have no way to add different types to the list.

Comment: That really is kind of the textbook case for using a common base class. Or you could make a class that stores a function pointer, and store a list of those, but that seems just as cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use functors in your list?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object

Comment: +1 For mentioning functors, which are superior to function pointer imho.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Fast Delegates: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx

This is an easy drop-in library that allows you to delegate pretty much anything and at a very high speed.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to implement, and even if it sounds stupid, I'd rather implement them myself to get a good understanding of how delegates work under the hood. But I'll check it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a pointer like that, but you could have a collection of `boost::any`, and put heterogeneous pointers (or any kind of *functors*) into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
void foo( void (T::*fptr)(), T& instance)
{
    // ...
}
```

I'm not going to play expert here, but I think this will work, if not I would like to know why.

Comment: fptr is the name of the resulting function pointer. Got nothing to do with the contents of T.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that, and you shouldn't do that even if you could, because it is against the spirit of the language. Create a base class with "fptr" as a pure virtual member, and inherit all your classes from that class.